# Javascript return function happens too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native

### **What my code should do**

I am creating a social media app using react native, and I have run into an problem with my code. I am trying to create a function which grabs all of the posts from all of the user's groups. To do this, I created a loop. The loop repeats once for every group the user is in. Every one loop gets the posts from one group. Every time the loop is called, a new function is called which gets the posts from a new group the user is in, then returns the posts back to the original function, which adds them to a full list of posts.

### **Problem**

The function getting the posts doesn't return the posts. I think that the code is not waiting for the posts to be returned, and moves on. Basically, when I console.log the posts on the function that got them, I get the correct posts, but when I console.log the entire list of posts, I get nothing back.

### **My question**

How can I wait for a value to be returned by a function, and not have the code instantly move on?

### **My code**

```
        runQ(group){
//this function actually gets the posts from the server (from firebase)
    var items = [];
    firebase.database().ref('posts/'+group).limitToLast(
           Math.floor(24/this.state.passGroups.length)*this.state.numOfPosts
        ).orderByKey().once ('value', (snap) => {
          snap.forEach ( (child) => {       
           items.push({
             //post info
         });
         });
    this.setState({passItems: items})
    console.log(items); //logs correct items.
    }).then(()=>{
       if( this.state.passItems.length != 0 ){return this.state.passItems;}
    })
    }


    //gets the user's groups, then sends out a request to each group for the newest posts.
      getItems(){
      //gets groups...
      //...    
    .then(()=>{
    var allItems = [];
    //allItems will be the big list of all of the posts.
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.passGroups.length; i++) {
       //sending request to runQ function to get posts.
       allItems.push(this.runQ(this.state.passGroups[i].name)) //allItems logs as allItems: ,,,,
    }
    })
    }
```

Comment: wrap it in a conditional and don't set that condition to true until you're ready to. .. so in your for-loop, you'd to a check to see if a condition is met (the length of allItems is what's expected, or x-seconds have elapsed), then you set the variable in the parent-scope to true and the code you want to have delayed is triggered. and you'll want to declare`allItems` outside of `.then()`

Comment: @admcfajn that just sees that the conditional is not true and skips over it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use async-await to make the for loop wait for each response.

First, you need to return the promise created by your Firebase call (you currently don't return anything from your `runQ()` function).
Change this line:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/'+group).limitToLast(
```

into:

```
return firebase.database().ref('posts/'+group).limitToLast(
```

Then tell your callback to the `getItems()` call to be an async function and await each response from `runQ()`:

```
  getItems(){
    //gets groups...
    //...    
    .then(async () => {
      var allItems = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.passGroups.length; i++) {
        allItems.push(await this.runQ(this.state.passGroups[i].name)) 
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Lennhom this works pretty well, but is there any way I could only return non null values?

Comment: @GIISE You mean from your callback where you have your `this.state.passItems.length != 0` condition? You need to return something from there, if what you want is to not have null values in the `allItems` array I suggest checking the awaited result and simply don't push it to the array if it's null.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to return a promise from runQ like this: `return firebase.database.....`

Then in the for loop you can do like this:

```
let allPromises = []
for (i = 0; i < this.state.passGroups.length; i++) {
  allPromises.push(this.runQ(this.state.passGroups[i].name))
}
Promise.all(allPromises).then(itemsArray => {
  allItems = allItems.concat(itemsArray)
})
```

Make sure that you have allItems declared in the right scope.